# Winsock.SendData equivalent with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, winsock

Can the following VB Script to open an IP cash drawer be done in Javascript instead?

```
Private Sub CashDrawerConnect_Click()
  Winsock1.Close
  ipaddr = "192.168.2.5"
  Winsock1.RemoteHost = ipaddr
  Winsock1.RemotePort = 30998
  Winsock1.Connect
  Sleep 250
  TxtOpStatus = "Connection to the cash drawer at " & ipaddr & " is established..."
  TxtOpStatus.Refresh
End Sub
Private Sub CashDrawerOpen_Click()
  If Winsock1.State = sckConnected Then
    Winsock1.SendData "opendrawer\0a"
  Else
    TxtOpStatus = "Not connected to the device"
    TxtOpStatus.Refresh
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it on javascript, but not while running on a browser.

You would need to install [nodejs](http://nodejs.org) and run your js file directly from the console.

This is a small example that would connect you the the drawer and send the "opendrawer" command on your example:

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.connect({port: 30998, host: "yourip"}, function() { 
    client.write("opendrawer\0a");
});
```

If however the server has access to the drawer the javascript code could just make a request to the server which would be on charge of opening the connection to the drawer and sending the payload (opendrawer).

If you use php you can take a look at the [sockets documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/book.sockets.php).

Comment: You can run JavaScript (JScript) from .NET

Comment: hmm... actually I wanted to run this from a web-app on iPad so I guess Javascript is out. Could it be done by php if there is a php server on the local network?

Comment: @JasonWood Yes, you can do that, i've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @JasonWood The PHP server doesn't necessarily have to be on a local network

Comment: @JuanMendes i think that he meant that it's reachable, not strictly on the local network.

Comment: Maybe, that's not what they he said though... I just wanted to point out that you can still use JSONP if the server is not local

Comment: That's great, thanks!! I did mean reachable but thanks for clarifying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using VB and JavaScript the calls are mostly the same, you just jhave to adapt it to the language. http://www.ostrosoft.com/oswinsck/oswinsck_javascript.asp

The following is a snippet that uses WinSock from JScript

```
var oWinsock;
var sServer = "192.168.2.5";
var nPort = 3098;
var bClose = false; 

oWinsock = new ActiveXObject("OSWINSCK.Winsock");
// Hooking up handlers
WScript.ConnectObject(oWinsock, "oWinsock_");
oWinsock.Connect(sServer, nPort);
WScript.Echo("Invalid URL");
bClose = true;

function oWinsock_OnConnect() {
  oWinsock.SendData('Your data');
}

function oWinsock_OnDataArrival(bytesTotal) {
  var sBuffer = oWinsock.GetDataBuffer();
  sSource = sSource + sBuffer;
}

function oWinsock_OnError(Number, Description, Scode, Source, 
    HelpFile, HelpContext, CancelDisplay) {
  WScript.Echo(Number + ': ' + Description);
}

function oWinsock_OnClose() {
  oWinsock.CloseWinsock();
  WScript.Echo(sSource);

  oWinsock = null;
  bClose = true;
}

while (!bClose) {
  WScript.Sleep(1);
}
```

In the browser? Not really, but you can use WebSockets http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

You'll need to implement a WebSocket server, so if you need to talk directly to a socket, you can't do it from a browser. But you could implement a proxy server that relays information between the socket server and the WebSocket server.

If you don't need two way communication, the best thing would be for your server to provide a webservice that wraps that socket request. Then your client can just make an AJAX call.

Comment: Websockets are not raw tcp sockets, they are tcp sockets which follow the websockets protocol, so they are not useful to connect them to something that doesn't speaks websockets, like the cash drawer

Comment: @albertein You do need to write a proxy websocket server as I mentioned